# Where does the proton's kinetic energy go when a proton and nuclei are fused together to create a heavy nucleus? I cannot solve this problem

Tags: particle-physics, waves, nuclear-physics, radiation, gamma-rays

[image]

The problem then states: estimate the minimum wavelength of the gamma ray photon.

The answer to this question is: 0.25 x 10^-11 - (binding energy of oxygen - the binding energy of F which is 0.04 x 10^-11). Then you use the hc/E = wavelength which I understand.

What I don't understand is why you would minus the kinetic energy from the energy released during nuclear fusion? Where does the kinetic energy of the proton go; does it turn into mass of fluorine?
I just don't understand; I would have added the oxygen binding energy and kinetic energy of the proton together and then subtracted that value from the binding energy of fluorine-18.

Comment: it  is important to  remember  keeping the signs for the simple calculation you state,   the kinetic energy of the proton is positive .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding energy of a proton in a nucleus is negative in the same way it is negative for an electron trapped in the potential well of a nucleus.  A free particle with no kinetic energy has 0 total energy.  A bound proton must have energy *added* to become free.

"I would have added the oxygen binding energy and kinetic energy of the proton together and then subtracted that value from the binding energy of fluorine-18" is *exactly* *right* except that the two binding energies are negative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I completely understand it now!